# Layout stretched after inserting it into a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout

I have a Layout with a ScrollView where I want to programatically insert another layout. So this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#56565A"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

inserted into this

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/live_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/live_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And I insert it like that

```
for (int i = 0; i < exercise.targetSets; i++) {
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View myView = factory.inflate(R.layout.live_set_item, null);
            TextView setName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.current_set);
            setName.setText(String.format("SET %d", i+1));

            scrollView.addView(myView);
        }
```

But when I run the app the inserted layout is twice as wide as it should.

[How it should look (How it looks in the Android Studio Editor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiEG9.png)

[Vs how it looks when inserted into the ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCUny.png)

So far I have tried to use a ConstraintLayout which didn't work. Or using different layout weights.

I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use the Layout Parameters for setting view custom params for height and width

as

```
val linearLayout = LinearLayout(requireActivity())
        val lp: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = (ParentView)findViewById(R.id.parent_view);
        val left_margin: Int = 3 //e.g
        val top_margin = 0
        val right_margin: Int = 3 //e.g
        val bottom_margin = 0
        lp.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin)
        val size = Point()
        val w = requireActivity().windowManager
        w.defaultDisplay.getSize(size)
        lp.width = size.x - 40
        lp.height = size.y
        linearLayout.layoutParams = lp
```

Or for better results, you can use the [recycler view](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example) to achieve the same result in better handling and just to create a single instance of adapter, which will be completely dependent on you list you are passing to the recycler view. also less code work to handle and debug.

Comment: It works! Thank you. And thank you for the tip with the Recycler View. I will look into that.

Comment: Hi FritzK, your welcome.. :).